# Copy data from one table to another based on an enum in first table

Tags: database, oracle, migration

I am migrating data from table B to table A & planning to delete table B later in Oracle.

Table A has fields `id`(primary key), `title`, `description`.

Table B has fields `id`(primary key), `parent_id`(foreign key(`id` from table A)), `info`, `type`(int, can be 1 OR 2 only).
Table B will have two rows for each `parent_id`, one having `type` = `1` and another with `type` = `2`.

Now, I want to introduce 2 new columns `info1` & `info2`to table A & fill them with respective data depending upon type enum.

Current approach:

```
alter table A add info1 VARCHAR2(32); 
alter table A add info2 VARCHAR2(32);

update A 
set 
info1 = (select info from B where type = 1 and A.id = B.parent_id),
info2 = (select info from B where type = 2 and A.id = B.parent_id);
```

What could be a efficient way to do this when we are doing it for large data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `oracle` is a DBMS, `mysql` is a DBMS to, which of the two are you using?   Please remove the inappropriate tag.

Comment: oracle it is. Removed mysql.

Comment: Enum are not supported in oracle, are you sure about your DBMS?

Comment: Its just a integer only, where we always store 1 or 2. We are using it as a enum. Sorry for the misunderstanding, I thought it would help in understanding the scenario better.